# How to install grab bar in aluminum siding

Tags: installation, siding, aluminum

A grab bar is needed in the exterior wall, which is made of aluminum siding.  How?

[image: location]

Ideally the grab bar would go at chest height on the narrow section above the steps (to the left of the garage door).  Best location would be in the middle of that section (in terms of left to right), but at the corner should also work.

Each section of siding measures almost 8 inches in height (up and down).

Later on there will be a ramp but that will take some time to organize and it's not needed yet.

Upstate NY climate, if that matters.

Comment: What's behind the siding?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you need to mount it to the siding? Are there no other options, such as a pair of posts? Siding penetrations need to be done carefully or they open the wall up to water ingress and decay. Please revise to add detail about the wall construction. (It's not _made_ of siding. It's just covered with it.) FYI, it's probably _steel_ siding. Test with a magnet if you're curious.

Comment: Also tell us the size (vertical dimension "to the weather"). That's important for any good answers. Small 3" and 4" profiles don't offer much space for mounting over the top. A clear photo of the scene would be golden.

Comment: Agree that a railing on posts would be waaay better than puncturing siding. If you sketched your needs, we could probably suggest good solutions.

Comment: The siding has no strength.  The bar must be attached to something structural that the siding is attached to.

Comment: Four screws into 1/2" OSB or plywood sheathing will be sufficient for a grab bar for most uses. When I was first installing grab bars I was determined to install them only into studs, but very quickly I found out that lesser strength attachments were sufficient for my situations. My house has insubstantial fibrous sheathing and that would not hold a grab bar. We don't know what is under this metal siding. I installed a long grab bar angled down a short flight of steps for an elderly couple. In that case I screwed into  studs, but in less critical applications I have found into studs not reqd.

Comment: So you want this on the wall next to and in the same plane as the garage door? Will this be a horizontal bar? If so, put it at about 36 inches above grade, not chest height. If you want it to act as a handrail for the steps, then angle it down to parallel the steps. Can you look inside the garage and see the position of the studs (vertical 2x4s) and what kind of sheathing you have under the siding?

Comment: You should have a suitable stud in the corner and one next to the garage door. Measure the length of bar you would need to fit at the angle you want. The dimension given for the bar (e.g., 16", 18", 24", etc.) is between the ends of the tubing. The outermost screws wil be 2.5" to 3" further apart.

Comment: @JimStewart - thanks but the person will need to pull themselves up with the grab bar -- it's not just for balance.

Comment: You can pull yourself up with a handrail paralleling the steps. When you reach the top it is easier to disengage the hand with an upward angled handrail than a verticl grab bar.  Check out the specifications for a handrail. You might want a handrail that curves around the corner and returns to the wall.

Comment: The vertical grab bars (about 10 inches long) have worked well for this person, who weighs about 120 lbs.  Large grab bars are quite pricey.

Answer (score 6):

A grab bar should be mounted into studs.

Most likely it is near a door, so get a stud sensor and find where the studs are from the inside.  Should have two studs together at the door side and the next one should be  ~16 inches away.

Take the carefully made measurements and transfer them to the outside.

You probably have 1/2 inch sheathing on the studs plus the siding, so will need at least 2 inch long or longer screws.

Try to mount near the top of the siding so you do not squeeze the sliding too much.

You will need to seal the grab bar where it mounts to the wall/sliding to prevent water/rain from getting into the wall.

Comment: Seal with what, please?  We'd like it to be vertical as that has worked well between the screen door and the front door.  If the corner stud is 4 inches wide, then would the screws go 2.5 inches in from the corner?

Comment: @aparente001   Usually some type of external caulking between the grab bar  and the sliding to seal the holes.

Comment: Thanks. If the corner stud is 4 inches wide, then would the screws go 2.5 inches in from the corner? Also, is 4 inches realistic?